# Why I am getting Syntax error in this Node JS code?

Tags: node.js, syntax-error

Hi I am starting with Node Js and tried a code as per the documentation [over here](https://github.com/jaxcore/bumblebee-hotword). I did everything accordingly but I am getting below error.

```
const Bumblebee = require('bumblebee-hotword');
    ^

SyntaxError: Identifier 'Bumblebee' has already been declared
at Loader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:147:18)
at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:48:21)
```

Here is the index.js code

```
import Bumblebee from "bumblebee-hotword";

const Bumblebee = require('bumblebee-hotword');

let bumblebee = new Bumblebee();

// set path to worker files
bumblebee.setWorkersPath('/bumblebee-workers');

// add hotword
bumblebee.addHotword('jarvis');

// set sensitivity from 0.0 to 1.0
bumblebee.setSensitivity(1.0);

bumblebee.on('hotword', function(hotword) {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
    console.log('hotword detected:', hotword);
});

bumblebee.start();
```

And here is the package.json

```
  {

  "name": "Hotword_template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",

"dependencies": {
  "bumblebee-hotword": "^0.2.1"
}
}
```

Also the required directory "bumblebee-workers" is in the same directory.
I don't know where I am doing wrong, any help is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Look at these two lines, you are importing and using constant variable of same name.

```
import Bumblebee from "bumblebee-hotword";

const Bumblebee = require('bumblebee-hotword');
```

Changing the name of **const** variable can solve your problem.